# Spring ConversionFailedException cannot be serialized to JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, log4j2

I use the [JSON layout logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSON_Layout) of Log4J2 for a Spring Boot (2.1.6) based web application.

I validate the incoming parameters of requests in [`Converter`s](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html).

If a parameter is not valid, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. That one gets wrapped in a `ConversionFailedException` which in turn gets wrapped in a `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`.

Now, when trying to log this exception with the JSON logger, the Jackson serialization runs into an endless recursion:

```
ERROR StatusLogger com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent["message"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["exception"]->org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException["cause"]->org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException["sourceType"]->org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor["resolvableType"]->org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"]->org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"])
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent["message"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["exception"]->org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException["cause"]->org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException["sourceType"]->org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor["resolvableType"]->org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"]->org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
...
```

The error seems to boil down to the fact that the `TypeDescriptor`s inside the `ConversionFailedException` cannot be serialized to JSON.

To reproduce:

```
val illegalArgumentException = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("your value is bad")
val conversionFailedException = org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException(TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.javaClass), TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.javaClass), "some bad value", illegalArgumentException)
val mapper = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper()

mapper.writeValueAsString(conversionFailedException)
```

Or, if you want to isolate the problem down to the smallest unit:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.javaClass))
```

What is the best way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you have received is because `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType` has a reference to itself: `componentType` which creates the infinite loop.

One way to avoid this is by globally excluding `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType` from JSON serialization/deserialization. You can do that by using Jackson's mixins:

```
@JsonIgnoreType
public class MyMixInForIgnoreType {}
```

Now, in a configuration class create a custom object mapper:

```
 @Bean
 @Primary 
 public ObjectMapper objectMapper () {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new Log4jJsonObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.class, MyMixInForIgnoreType.class);
    return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you have any idea how to set this for the `Log4jJsonObjectMapper`?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the `Log4jJsonObjectMapper` does not use Spring dependency injection to create the instance. It seems like I need to create a customized `Layout` in order to make sure that my logging doesn't break :-(